# Select and show different POI on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, contextmenu, point-of-interest

I have been searching but had no luck with finding solution to my problem. Since I am beginner in programming this map thing is a bit difficult.

I know how to show map, my location and few overlayed items. SO far so good. Part of my app should be map with few different groups of POI (point of interest), like petrol station, hospitals etc.

How can I make user choose witch of these POI groups to be shown. If you could point me to some tutorial or something. I used all of what I can from android developer site.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create them in different Overlay and dinamicly remove or add it to the map something like that

```
        if ( mapView.getOverlays().contains(weatherOverlay) ) {
            mapView.getOverlays().remove(weatherOverlay);
        }
        if ( weatherButton.isChecked() ) {
            mapView.getOverlays().add(weatherOverlay);
        }
```

Comment: I will try to make this and will let you know did it help. If there is some examples post it. Thanks